# Exchange 2016 CU8 AdvancedDataGovernanceLogs

Tags: windows, email, exchange, email-server, exchange-2016

This is a fresh install of Exchange 2016 CU8 on windows server 2016 standard.

Driver letters:

C: OS

D: Exchange 2016 CU8 ISO (mounted)

After Exchange 2016 CU8 install, the ISO was dismounted and I setup a new data drive for Exchange. The data drive took drive letter D: by default. When I restarted the server, D:\AdvancedDataGovernanceLogs folder was created.

If I change the data drive letter from D: to something else like E: drive, D:\AdvancedDataGovernanceLogs folder does not get created when the server is restarted.

What is AdvancedDataGovernanceLogs folder and how do you change the location?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the AdvancedDataGovernanceLogs on your D:\ drive is an Exchange 2016 bug which Microsoft will fix / close in CU 11 for Exchange 2016 as written [here](https://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/436-d-advanceddatagovernancelogs-created-on-exchange-2016.html). So for the moment there is no real way you can do to fix the issue.